# Swift СoreData Predicate returns without one record

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

Such a problem that in one screen my getCount function returns for example 5 records

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
      return
    }
    var managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
      managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
     print(getCount(viewContext2:  managedContext)) // 5


func getCount(viewContext2:  NSManagedObjectContext)-> Int{

let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Cart> = Cart.fetchRequest()

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "real_id == %@","2086" )

do {
let resCart1ById2 =  try  viewContext2.fetch(fetchRequest)
     
    return resCart1ById2.count //   5 
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
return -1

}
```

When switching to another child screen, the same function returns 4, does not see one record
How can the problem be solved?

Comment: Impossible to answer with so little information. Have you used a debugger or print statements to check which element is missing (I assume 5 is the correct number)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not enough information to be sure, but since you have a `viewContext2`, maybe you're using mutiple contexts? Changes on one context don't automatically appear in another one.